# cask init does not create ~/.cask file

Tags: osx, cask

I actually know very little about `cask`. I discover it after browsing the `emacs` module of [prezto](https://github.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto)

In this prezto module, the `cask` command alias will not be created unless there exists a `.cask` file.

I have run `cask init` but the file is still absent. Is it right for me to expect this file to be created by `cask init`?

Here is the link to the key file in the said `emacs` module https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sorin-ionescu/prezto/master/modules/emacs/init.zsh

Comment: Is Cask actually [installed](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/installation.html#package-managers)?

Comment: I installed it using `brew`

Comment: You can create yourself a Cask file, with the dependencies you want. But cask [init](http://cask.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/usage.html#cask-init) is supposed to create the Cask file. If it is not the case, something is probably wrong. Please update your question with more informations related to the platform you're currently working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/.cask/` is the standard installation directory for Cask.  Since you installed Cask in a non-standard way, you do not have this directory and you don't need to create it.  Cask is fully functional.

However, the prezto module was written before the Homebrew formula existed, and hasn't been updated since, so it doesn't know about Homebrew's installation directory and consequently doesn't find cask.  You need to fix the Prezto module.

Source: I contribute to Cask, and wrote this Prezto module.  But I've since stopped to use Prezto, and don't maintain it anymore.

Comment: Thanks! If you are not using Prezto now, what are you using instead? Just curious

Comment: @AnthonyKong My own configuration.